# PasswordPropertyText not working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a SharePoint web part with a web-browsable property that stores a password. I've decorated the property with the PasswordPropertyText attribute but whenever I edit the web part it shows the actual password rather than dots or asterisks. Here is my property declaration:

```
<Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared), _
PasswordPropertyText(True), _
WebBrowsable(True), _
WebDisplayName("Your Password"), _
Public Property MyPassword() As String
    Get
        return m_myPassword
    End Get

    Set(value as String)
        m_myPassword = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Does SharePoint 2007 respect this attribute, or am I just not using it correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible to configure a password property to display as you wish with attribute decorations.

You need to implement a custom editor part and handle the MyPassword property there. See this [article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.editorpart.aspx) for a code sample. Render the MyPassword property with the standard ASP.NET TextBox control and set its TextMode property set to `password`.

Answer (score 1):

The atrribute only makes the text show up as asterisks when viewed in the property window of Visual Studio or any control thats is a PropertyGrid.

I'm afraid I can't find anything at the moment relating to making a WebParts property show up as a password field.  I'll try to find this out though as I would like to know myself.